# Unable to run git from command line

Tags: windows, git, symfony

I have installed GIT for Windows right now. And when I am running this into my symfony project to reinstall the vendors by

```
php bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

Then i am getting an error

```
git' is not recognized as internal or external command
```

I have set the environmental variables also as

```
c:/programme files/git/cmd
```

Now what should I do?
I have tried also for environmental variables

```
c:/program files/git/bin
```

but I am getting the same error

Comment: How your path environment variable looks like now?

Comment: its like c:/program files/git/bin

Comment: I mean the **whole** path environment variable, not only the part you added.

Comment: c:\program files\git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

- My `PATH` has backslashes instead of forward ones.
- your first line contains a typo, should be `c:\program files\git\cmd`

One more: If your path includes spaces, enclose it in quotes:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"
```

Comment: yep it has forward slashes only. sorry for that

Comment: I just uninstall the git and reinstall in c drive instead of program files. i think it is due to space in between program and files

Comment: Path within Windows might also be C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd when using a 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 13):

During Git installation, in the path environment settings chose the following one.
Even I had the same problem, of git not executed on my normal Command Line, but i just reinstalled it with the setting "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just open cmd and run this command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"
```